# Zend Famework: accessing a parameter/variable from view and using them in controller

Tags: zend-framework

I have some variables in my view tht are hyperlinks:

```
<td><a href=""><?php echo $this->data1;?></a></td>
<td><a href=""><?php echo $this->data2;?></a></td>
```

Once clicked, i would like these variables to be accessible in a controller.

I hope I'm being clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

What you have between your `<a>` and your `</a>` tags is the link text. So it doesn't make sense to  say that's data. It is merely a strong which is used as linktext.

I advice you to learn / read about PHP before you start using a framework like Zend Framework.

What you are asking for is usually done either via $_POST array or $_GET array.

The post array can be populated via form submission, the get array can be populated via querystring parameters.

What you want, is a link with parameters like this:

```
<a href="your/link/url?parameter=value&anotherParameter=anotherValue">Linktext</a>
```

This will populate the $_GET array and you can retrieve the two parameters with:

```
$parameter       = $_GET['parameter'];
$aotherParameter = $_GET['anotherParameter'];
```

In Zend Framework you could do the same via url view helper and other convencience functions:

```
<?php
   $targetUrl = $this->url(array(
       'controller'       => 'mycontroller',
       'action'           => 'my-action',
       'parameter'        => 'value',
       'anotherParameter' => 'anotherValue'), null, TRUE);
?>

<a href="<?php echo $targetUrl; ?>">Linktext</a>
```

In the action you could get the parameters from the response object like this:

```
$parameter = $this->getRequest->getParam('parameter');
```

This does essentially the same, the handling of the $_GET array is just wrapped.

Comment: +1 for learning PHP before any framework, you need to know the web programming basics before hoping to switch to higher gears

Answer (score -1):

This is one way,

If I understand, you need to pass that variable to $_REQUEST for example you can:

```
 <a href="<?= $this->baseUrl(); ?>?my_variable=<?= $this->data1; ?>">
       <?php echo $this->data1;?>
 </a>
```

and in controller get that variable

```
 $this->getRequest()->getParam('my_variable');
```

Comment: This is unreadable. `baseUrl` is not suitable for creating links.